# com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication won't run unless you update Google Play service

Tags: android, google-play-services

I used to use the MAP activity in the Android studio, but this activity is happening.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0rtq.png)
I installed Google Play Service and I also did the compile thing.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kimej.test1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:.12'
}
```

Of course, the API key input has been entered, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

try this, its work for me.
change :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'
```

Comment: Thank you!! Now it's going well!

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the suggested answer in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329368/com-android-tools-fd-runtime-bootstrapapplication-wont-run-unless-you-update-go) by downgrading the version of Google Play Service.

So instead of `com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'` use `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'`

For more information, check this [thread](https://github.com/google/iosched/issues/37).

Answer (score 0):

Change
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'`
to
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'`